# Discord bot not able to contact discord servers when using docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, discord.js

I recently started learning docker and have been running into issues when using docker-compose
The discord bot works perfectly when you use `docker run` but whenever I run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error

```js
app_1  | /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:93
app_1  |         throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request.method, request.path);
app_1  |               ^
app_1  | 
app_1  | HTTPError [FetchError]: request to https://discord.com/api/v7/gateway/bot failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN discord.com
app_1  |     at RequestHandler.execute (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:93:15)
app_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
app_1  |     at async RequestHandler.push (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
app_1  |     at async WebSocketManager.connect (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:138:9)
app_1  |     at async Client.login (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:223:7) {
app_1  |   code: 500,
app_1  |   method: 'get',
app_1  |   path: '/gateway/bot'
app_1  | }
app_1  | npm ERR! code 1
app_1  | npm ERR! path /app
app_1  | npm ERR! command failed
app_1  | npm ERR! command sh -c tsc && node dist/index.js
app_1  | 
app_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-11T03_27_59_096Z-debug.log
bot_app_1 exited with code 1
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY .env ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - app-data:/app/data
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: db

volumes:
  app-data: {}
  db-data: {}
```

And here is my main code which helps me connect to discord

```js
import { Client, Message, Guild } from "discord.js";
import { commands } from "./commands/index";
import { config } from "dotenv";
export const client = new Client();
config();
client.on("ready", async () => {
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch("771187253937438762");
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`over ${guild.memberCount} furries`, {
    type: "WATCHING",
  });
});
client.on("message", async (msg) => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  if (msg.author.id == client.user?.id) return;
  if (!msg.content.startsWith(process.env.BOT_PREFIX)) return;
  const [cmd, ...args] = msg.content
    .slice(process.env.BOT_PREFIX.length)
    .replace(/ +/g, " ")
    .split(" ");
  const commandClass = commands.find((command) => {
    return command.aliases.some((c) => c.toLowerCase() === cmd.toLowerCase());
  });
  if (!commandClass) return;

    await commandClass.execute({
      msg: msg as Message & { guild: Guild },
      cmd,
      args: args,
    }).catch((e)=>{
      console.log(e);
    });
});
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

If anyone can help me with this question that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up`? You might also want to try and restart Docker using `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: I tried that, but it says that `sudo: service: command not found`. For more information i use archlinux so i tried `systemctl restart docker` but it didn't fix the issue. Thank you for replying though.

Comment: Did you try the compose down, up too? Also what does your `daemon.js` file look like for docker?

Comment: I did try the compose down up. what is a `daemon.js` file, i do not have it.

Comment: You can create this file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and put `{ "dns": ["1.1.1.1", "1.0.0.1"] }` in it

Comment: alright ill try it. i created a file called `daemon.json` and added the following line into the dockerfile `COPY daemon.json /etc/docker/` but it still isn't working, do i copy it into my pc or my project file? Im assuming you put it into your pc, im doing that now. EDIT: it didn't seem to work, still returning the same error

Comment: No it's a local file for the host machine in `/etc/docker/`, you'll need to restart docker with `systemctl` after that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227172/discussion-between-voxal-and-pentium1080ti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the network for your discord bot in your `docker-compose.yml`

`network_mode: bridge` - This is the easiest way to get it to work

You can incorperate this into the compose file like:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - app-data:/app/data
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: db
    network_mode: bridge

volumes:
  app-data: {}
  db-data: {}
```

You can read more about the network types in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/)